# After using checkpoint in Pyspark the program run faster, why?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My spark setting is like that :

```
  spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName('app_name') \
    .setMaster("local[4]") \
    .set('spark.executor.memory', "8g") \
    .set('spark.executor.cores', 4) \
    .set('spark.task.cpus', 1)
  sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=spark_conf)
  sc.setCheckpointDir(dirName='checkpoint')
```

When I do not have any checkpoint in the spark chain and my program is like this:

```
  result = sc.parallelize(group, 4) \
    .map(func_read, preservesPartitioning=True)\
    .map(func2,preservesPartitioning=True) \
    .flatMap(df_to_dic, preservesPartitioning=True) \
    .reduceByKey(func3) \
    .map(func4, preservesPartitioning=True) \
    .reduceByKey(func5) \
    .map(write_to_db) \
    .count()
```

Running time is about 8 hours.
But when I use checkpoint and cache RDD like this:

```
result = sc.parallelize(group, 4) \
    .map(func_read, preservesPartitioning=True)\
    .map(func2,preservesPartitioning=True) \
    .flatMap(df_to_dic, preservesPartitioning=True) \
    .reduceByKey(func3) \
    .map(func4, preservesPartitioning=True) \
    .reduceByKey(func5) \
    .map(write_to_db)
result.cache()
result.checkpoint()
result.count()
```

The program run in about 3 hours. Would you please guide how it is possible that after caching RDD and using checkpoint the program run faster?

Any help would be really appreciated.